# How to get text content of slot?

Tags: javascript, html, stenciljs

We can have stencilJS element with `slot` as below

```js
<my-component>123</my-component>
```

I'm trying to get the value of `123` from my `render` method itself, wondering if that is possible?

```js
@Component({ tag: 'my-component' })
export class MyComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div><slot /></div>
    )
  }
}
```

I would like to do some string formatting on `123` instead of rendering `slot` directly

Comment: An alternative would be to have it as a property instead.

Comment: @Thomas: Yup of course, but that would not be ideal

Answer (score 2):

```js
import { Element } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({ tag: 'my-component' })
export class MyComponent {
  /**
   * Reference to host element
   */
  @Element() host: HTMLElement;

  componentWillRender() {
    console.log(this.host.innerHTML)
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div><slot /></div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: It's useless, because `slot` will still be rendered isnt it

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here then, why do you use slot when you don't want it rendered?

Comment: I want to use `slot` so that developer can define like a button `<my-component>123</my-component>`, but instead of showing 123 directly, I would like to have some formatting and to render 123.00 instead

Answer (score 2):

In web components, the content inside of it is part of the main DOM, too. This content is not going to show if you don't use slots; but, the content is going to project next to the #shadow-root anyway (check it using the chrome developer tools in the "elements" section).

[image]

So, if you do not want to show the content using default slots, you can use the property decorator `@Element()` and declare a property of type HTMLElement:

Then, you can access to the content via `innerHTML` or `innerText`.

Finally, you can format the content. Check the code snippet bellow:

```js
import { Component, Element, h } from "@stencil/core";
@Component({
    tag: 'my-component',
    styleUrl: 'my-component.css',
    shadow: true
})

export class MyComponent {
    @Element() element: HTMLElement;

    formatContent(content: any) {
        if ( isNaN(content)){
            // Your format here
            return content;
        } else {
            return content + '.00';
        }
    }
    render() {
        return [
            // Commented slot tag
            // <slot></slot>,
            <div> {this.formatContent(this.element.innerHTML)} </div>
        ];
    }
}
```

Using three times the web component with 2 strings and a number as a entry data, the result should be:

```
My text
My text 2
123.00
```